# Scrollable div (css + js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I basically have one smaller div with overflow set to auto. Inside I have another, big div of the size of the grid and inside this div I have canvas element, that should have the size of the first smaller div.

What I want to achieve is to **have the canvas always shown in the smaller div, no matter where I scrolled.**

I set the position of canvas to relative and the top and left attributes are set as scrollTop and scrollLeft in javascript whenever I scroll. This way my canvas will have always fixed size ( no performance issues) and in javascript I can compute the position in which I am scrolled in.

```
var s=document.getElementById("scrollable");
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");

c.width=400;
c.height=400;

var maxw = s.scrollWidth;
var maxh = s.scrollHeight;

s.onscroll = function(){
    c.style.top = s.scrollTop + "px";
    c.style.left = s.scrollLeft + "px";    
}
```

**The problem I am having is that when I reach the end of scrolling, canvas seems to overflow the big div (thanks to size of the scrollbars I believe) and thus the big div's size is increasing and scrolling continues while it shouldn't.**

Link to simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwynt/1/

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the question... What do you want to do with the _grid_ ?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem (but that may just be my fancy Mac's auto-hidden scrollbars). Is the canvas always going to be the same size as the smaller div?

Comment: I want to have grid inside some div. And if that grid is bigger than the div, I want be able to use scrollbars to move through the grid. When my grid was to big, my canvas was big and my browser started to freez. So I would like to have big div instead of big canvas. So the canvas will be replaced by div, and inside this div I want to place canvas that will be "moved" on top of the parent div depending on where I am scrolled and it will always show up no matter where my scrollbars are.

Comment: David, yes the canvas should always be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about the scrollbars causing the problem.  they shrink the viewable area of your div, so the canvas is always overflowing over the right and bottom (since you keep moving the canvas down, you can never scroll all the way there).  You can add this to your "wrap" div to fix:

```
overflow:hidden
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3XPB/